# Why are colors randomly removed from colormap?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, colormap

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'bar_groups': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B'],
        'color_groups': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2],
        0: [0.258, 0.087, 0.168, 0.241, 0.182, 0.236, 0.231, 0.092, 0.283, 0.186],
        1: [0.212, 0.208, 0.135, 0.24, 0.256, 0.27, 0.218, 0.151, 0.162, 0.18],
        2: [0.009, 0.062, 0.031, 0.017, 0.027, 0.02, 0.043, 0.087, 0.011, 0.04],
        3: [0.006, 0.015, 0.006, 0.009, 0.009, 0.01, 0.016, 0.006, 0.004, 0.011],
        4: [0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.007, 0.005, 0.18, 0.002, 0.025, 0.004],
        5: [0.268, 0.269, 0.262, 0.278, 0.278, 0.269, 0.19, 0.229, 0.395, 0.234],
        6: [0.004, 0.017, 0.008, 0.009, 0.018, 0.002, 0.005, 0.012, 0.002, 0.04],
        7: [0.242, 0.338, 0.387, 0.204, 0.222, 0.188, 0.117, 0.422, 0.117, 0.306],
        8: [0.006, 0.015, 0.006, 0.009, 0.009, 0.01, 0.016, 0.006, 0.004, 0.011]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
          
# Plot code

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,7))
# bars on the left 
df_target = df.groupby(["bar_groups", "color_groups"]).size()
df_target = (df_target / df_target.groupby("bar_groups").transform(sum)).unstack(level='color_groups')
df_target.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True, position=1, colormap='Set3', width=0.4, ax=ax, edgecolor='grey')

# bars on the right
df_prob = df[['bar_groups', 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]].groupby('bar_groups').mean()
df_prob.plot.bar(stacked=True, ax=ax, position=0, cmap='Set3', width=0.4, legend=False, alpha=0.6, edgecolor='grey')
ax.set_xlim(-0.75,9)
ax.set_ylabel('Actual (left) & Predicted (right) bars')
plt.title('Grouped bar chart')
```

For external reasons I had to remove the last column (`8`) and now the colors completely changed - matplotlib seems to be removing random colors in the sequence (pink, purple).

Comment: Hi! Would you mind elaborating what you mean by " I had to remove the last column (8)"? What parts of the code did you adapt?

Comment: @SimonDavid hi! Edited that a bit. Basically because of changes in my analysis I don't need that column anymore so I just removed it, so now the second groupby goes from 0-7. I just re-ran the code in the post as it is and, strangely, the columns on the left are missing some colours but the columns on the right are okay (pink and purple still there)

Answer (score 0):

#### `df_target`

```
color_groups         1         2     3         4     5         6         7     8
bar_groups                                                                      
A             0.333333  0.333333   NaN       NaN   NaN  0.333333       NaN   NaN
B                  NaN  0.250000  0.25       NaN  0.25       NaN       NaN  0.25
C             0.333333       NaN   NaN  0.333333   NaN       NaN  0.333333   NaN
```

#### `df_prob`

```
                   0         1         2         3        4         5         6        7         8
bar_groups                                                                                        
A           0.193667  0.230000  0.030333  0.010333  0.00300  0.268667  0.007667  0.25600  0.010333
B           0.157000  0.180500  0.046250  0.008000  0.00375  0.250750  0.019500  0.33425  0.008000
C           0.251667  0.206667  0.023667  0.009667  0.06900  0.287667  0.005333  0.14600  0.009667
```

- The dataframes do not have the same columns, as such `cmap` will not apply the same colors to the two plot calls.
- The column names must be mapped to specific colors, which are then passed to the `color` parameter.
- These are the colors for `'Set3'`

  - [image]
  - `mpl.colormaps['Set3'](range(9)` creates a list of 9 colors from `'Set3'`, which corresponds to the column names, `0, 1, 2, ..., 8`.
  - [Creating Colormaps in Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html)

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create a dict where each column name is mapped to a specific color
color = dict(zip(range(9), mpl.colormaps['Set3'](range(9))))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 7))
# bars on the left 
df_target = df.groupby(["bar_groups", "color_groups"]).size()
df_target = (df_target / df_target.groupby("bar_groups").transform(sum)).unstack(level='color_groups')
df_target.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True, position=1, color=color, width=0.4,  ax=ax, edgecolor='grey')


# bars on the right
df_prob = df[['bar_groups', 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]].groupby('bar_groups').mean()
df_prob.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=ax, position=0, color=color, width=0.4, rot=0, legend=True, alpha=0.6, edgecolor='grey')
ax.set_xlim(-0.5, 2.5)
ax.set(title='Grouped bar chart', ylabel='Actual (left) & Predicted (right) bars', xlabel='Bar Groups')

ax.legend(title='Color Groups', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), loc='center left', frameon=False)
```

- With the legend showing for both plots, see the colors for a given column name are the same.

[image]

#### Plot with `cmap='Set3'`

- See in the legend that the colors are not the same for a given column name.

[image]